# Video stream for existing VoIP system - which libraries should be used?

Tags: c++, audio, video, ffmpeg, libvlc

The project I'm currently working on, requires an addition to the already existing VoIP capabilities. The core for speech processing is in C, the remainder is in C++ with Qt - the audio is handled via portaudio. The connection between users is currently established via UDP, which I think has to be changed for the planned video connection. Developing platform is Windows on VS2012 - however, the system is cross-platform.

In a nutshell, what I want to do is: Grab the video signal from a webcam, synchronize audio coming from C core and video from webcam and use a library and codecs for (de-)coding/muxing the signals on the respective sides and sending via RTP. The system should be capable of multicast transmission.

I did some research for possible libraries and stumbled upon ffmpeg and libVLC. For the codec I thought about using x264. And if I'm correct, ffmpeg and libVLC should both be capable of what I'm looking for?

However I'm not sure which one to pick, and from their documentations I really can't extract, which library is the better fit. Has anybody had similar problems and can help me out - I'm quite a newbie, when it comes to video processing and encoding.

Extra question: Do you have any hints or approaches on syncing the video and audio signals?

Comment: You could write an abstraction layer that would allow you to easily switch out the back end or compare their performance/suitability.  I expect either library would be acceptable.  The main issue you would have is licences particularly if using x264 for encoding as it is under the GPL which would mean your whole application would need to be GPL licensed.

Comment: The abstraction layer seems like a good idea. I thought that the licensing will be problematic with x264. So WebM/VP8 as a codec would be a solution, I guess? Then FFmpeg can used under the LGPL with libvpx?

Comment: Yes you could use VP8 (or VP9), I think you will still be able to decode h.264 with the lgpl variant of ffmpeg but not encode it as this requires x264.  Unless of course you are prepared to GPL your application.

Comment: As for sync, sync the video presentation timestamp (PTS) to the audio stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is interested, this is what I ended up doing:

I am using the WebM container format, VP8 with Vorbis currently (but going to change to VP9 with Opus soon if out of beta), handled by ffmpeg/libav libraries for encoding/decoding/muxing etc. and SDL for displaying and threading. ffmpeg/libav was cross-compiled on Unix with LGPL support to keep our project closed source.